# mongodb query in 2 collections

Tags: mongodb

I have define 2 reconds in 2 collections separately in one mongo db like this

```
order:

{

    "_id" : ObjectId("53142f58c781abdd1d836fcd"),
    "number" : "order1",
    "user" : ObjectId("53159bd7d941aba0621073e3")
}

user

{

    "_id" : ObjectId("53159bd7d941aba0621073e3"),
    "name" : "user1",
    "gender" : "male"

}
```

when I use this command in console, it can not execute
**db.orders.find({user: db.user['_id']})** or **db.orders.find({user: user['_id']}),**

is there anything wrong? Thanks!

Comment: If your next step is to try to do this outside of a console application, you'll want to do some searches for the challenges of doing schema design in Mongo when there aren't JOINs like in a traditional RDBMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way is to:

```
> var user = db.users.findOne({name: 'user1'}); 
> db.orders.find({user: user._id});
```

This way can be a bit more flexible especially if you want to return orders for multiple users etc.

Taking your comment:

> Thanks, but actually, I want to search all the orders of all users, not only one user. So what would I do? Thanks

```
db.users.find().forEach(function(doc){
    printJson(db.orders.find({user: doc._id}));
});
```

Comment: Thanks, does the loop must have? Or can we use like in or other keyword to get the result? Thanks!

Comment: @user3003466 it depends on what you mean by searhcing by all users. I mean you could just do a find on the orders table and you will be searching by all users

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
db.order.find({'user':db.users.findOne({'name':'user1'})._id})
```

All you need to do is to make a query and check the output before inserting it into the query.

i.e. check that:

```
db.users.findOne({'name':'user1'})._id
```

has the output:

```
ObjectId("53159bd7d941aba0621073e3")
```

If you want to run larger queries, you're going to have to change your structure. Remember that Mongodb doesn't do joins so you'll need to do create a user document that looks like this:

```
user
{
 "name":"user1",
 "gender":"male",
 "orders":[
    {
     'number':'order1'
    }
 ]
}
```

You can then update this using:

```
 db.user.update({'_id':ObjectId('blah')}, {'orders':{$push:{'number':'order2'}})
```

This will then start you with order tracking.

Mongo will be able to find using the following:

```
 db.user.find({'orders.numbers':'order2'})
```

returning the full user record

Comment: Thanks, but actually, I want to search all the orders of all users, not only one user. So what would I do? Thanks!

Comment: Aha - I think you're going to have to redesign!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can help this solution:

```
use orders
db.getCollection('order').find({},{'_id':1})
db.getCollection('user').find({},{'_id':1})
```